# This configuration section cannot be used at this path. with "<anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />"

Tags: wcf, session, iis

I am having an error in my application related to session lost in specific wcf service call , my hosting company solved it by adding the following tags

```
 <security>
  <authentication>
    <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
  </authentication>
</security>
```

However now when I am deploying live on another server I am getting the error 
This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  with the anonymousAuthenticaiton in red.

I googled it and they said I must change it in ApplicationConfig , and I changed as the following

```
   <section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
                <section name="basicAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
                <section name="clientCertificateMappingAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
                <section name="digestAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
                <section name="iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
                <section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

But I am still facing th same error , any help would be appreciated I am so stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like on the other server there's a higher up config that's preventing you from applying the anonymous config.

You or your admin need to check the parent config file to ensure it not being blocked.